# Error More than one node matching the query when running custom MFTF Test

Tags: magento2.3.2, mftf, whitelist

When running my custom mftf test, I get the error

```
More than one node matching the query: /entities/entity/requiredEntity[@type='custom_attribute_array'].Exception occurred parsing action at StepKey "disableWYSYWYG"
```

This happens when I add several  entries in my custom data file.
Interestingly it does not happen when using a predefined data entity with several required entities.
Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that I had added CUSTOM_MODULE_PATHS in the .env file of MFTF. This was required in earlier versions of MFTF and I forgot to remove it. So my module was loaded twice and that is why the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Check 
`etc/config.xml` the path is defined twice in 2 different plugins or your plugin loaded twice